# Web base application-load balancer

Tags: nginx, docker, java, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have two application Java base and Go base application. What is the best way to build a traffic distribution that will send 30% of request traffic to Java base application and 70% to Go base application using load balancer. This activity will be built on a docker composer file or Kubernetes Is there a better way to archive this task.?

Answer (score 2):

Nginx does [weighted routing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#weights). If you get your traffic to Nginx you can then send it out to the containers to service the requests however you like.

```
upstream backend {
  server backend1.example.com weight=5;
  server backend2.example.com;
  server 192.0.0.1 backup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with different controllers like:

- [Contur/Heptio](https://github.com/heptio/contour/blob/master/docs/ingressroute.md#upstream-weighting)
- [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#traffic-splitting)
- [Nginx Ingress for kubernetes](https://www.nginx.com/blog/choosing-nginx-plus-load-balancing-techniques/#weights)
- [istio traffic distribution](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/traffic-shifting/) and [routing](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-versions)

Additional resources:

- [Top ingress controller](https://caylent.com/kubernetes-top-ingress-controllers/)
- [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers)

Hope this help.